# What's the point of things like intelligence/wisdom scores, when those are the predominantly characteristics of the player?

Tags: ability-scores, player-agency

While I understand the role of things like strength (you can/can't lift that), dexterity, constitution, etc. as character attributes, I really can't make sense of intelligence/wisdom scores.

If a player notices that you can go around the monster, or just naturally has good memory, they're going to do clever and insightful things even if they have INT/WIS of 1.

Comment: What game and edition are you asking about? Please include a tag to indicate this. There are thousands of RPGs and we can't provide an answer without knowing which one the question is about. This may be answerable based on rules (hence needing to know the game and edition) but if this is merely a discussion prompt or seeking people's opinions then [you would be better off with a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/14878). This site isn't build for those types of questions.